# Read Latest Hotmail Emails in Python

Tags: python, email, hotmail

I've been searching for a way to get the latest emails from my hotmail account (specifically the FROM and MESSAGE) using Python. The solutions mostly seem to be for gmail which isn't working as I would like.

Example 1: Using the Gmail examples - msg spits out a lot of unwanted data and the attempt to get subject, to and from returns blanks for each.

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
mail.login('myemail@hotmail.com', 'password')
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

for i in range(1, 5):
    typ, msg_data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
    for response_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            # print(response_part[1])
            msg = email.message_from_string(str(response_part[1]))
            print(msg)
            for header in [ 'subject', 'to', 'from' ]:
                print('%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), msg[header]))

mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

Example 2: Gets last outlook email contents but cannot seem to get more (e.g. last 5)

```
import imaplib
msrvr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com', 993)

unm = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
pwd = 'password'
msrvr.login(unm, pwd)

print(str(len(msrvr.select('inbox'))))

stat,cnt = msrvr.select('inbox')

print(str(len(cnt)))

for i in range(0,5):

    stat,dta = msrvr.fetch(cnt[i], '(BODY[TEXT])')
    print(dta[0][1])

msrvr.close()
msrvr.logout()
```

Any thoughts how I could get the last 5 emails with FROM and MESSAGE?

Comment: In the first example, have you tried that after 
`msg = email.message_from_string(str(response_part[1]))`
to access the From, To and Subject using `msg['From']`, `msg['To']`, `msg['Subject']` respectively?

Also, can you give a better explanation for example 2? Do you mean that you cannot fetch the email with id = 6 for example?